# What precautions do I need to take when sharing an AWS Amplify project publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm creating [a security camera IoT project](https://github.com/owntheweb/twin-tiger-security-camera) that uploads images to S3 and will soon offer a UI to review those images. AWS Amplify is being used to make this happen quickly.

As I get started on the Amplify side of things, I'm noticing a config file that has very specifically named attributes and values. The `team-provider-info.json` file in particular that isn't ignored is very specific:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "awscloudformation": {
            "AuthRoleName": "amplify-twintigersecurityweb-dev-123456-authRole",
            "UnauthRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::111164163333:role/amplify-twintigersecurityweb-dev-123456-unauthRole",
            "AuthRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::111164163333:role/amplify-twintigersecurityweb-dev-123456-authRole",
            "Region": "us-east-1",
            "DeploymentBucketName": "amplify-twintigersecurityweb-dev-123456-deployment",
            "UnauthRoleName": "amplify-twintigersecurityweb-dev-123456-unauthRole",
            "StackName": "amplify-twintigersecurityweb-dev-123456",
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:111164163333:stack/amplify-twintigersecurityweb-dev-123456/88888888-8888-8888-8888-888838f58888",
            "AmplifyAppId": "dddd7dx2zipppp"
        }
    }
}
```

May I post this to my public repository without worry? Is there a chance for conflict in naming? How would one pull this in for use in their new project?

Answer (score 1):

Per [AWS Amplify documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#quickstart):

> If you want to share a project publicly and open source your serverless infrastructure, you should remove or put the amplify/team-provider-info.json file in gitignore file.

At a glance, everything else generated by `amplify init` NOT in the .gitignore file is ok to share. e.g. project-config.json and backend-config.json.

Add this to .gitignore:

```
# not to share if public
amplify/team-provider-info.json
```